# Creating separate plist files from dictionaries, zipping them up and then saving the zip, all without temporary storage?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, zip, save

So I have a bunch of dictionaries that all are supposed to go into separate plists, some even in specific subfolders, and then I need to zip all these up into one zip file and save that file to the disk.

Now… What would be the best way to do this in code? Can I do it without first saving each dictionary to a separate file on the disk? And which zip library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without first saving each dictionary to a separate file on disk.  To convert a dictionary to a plist in memory, use `+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:]` or the equivalent `CFPropertyListCreateData`.  To make zip files, I've used the "minizip" add-on that comes with the [zlib](http://zlib.net) library.  I think there are some C++ or Objective-C wrappers for handling zip files more conveniently, but it's not that hard anyway.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect. :)

Now to figure out how to create subdirectories…